# Counter to remove a record pl/sql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a problem with the procedure that should remove one product at a time based on the order number and the product number from the tables below. I tried the procedure initially and it worked only when removing the first pno from odetails, and inserting into the required tables. However, my problem is when an order has more than one product number and wanted to remove One By One. I usually get an error with the last item when I try to remove it and also the order won't be deleted because there is no delete on this table. In summary How do to remove the last ono from orders once all the removing processes finish? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ONE_BY_ONE( ORD_NUM IN NUMBER(5), PRO_NUM IN NUMBER(5))
AS
CURSOR CUR1
IS
SELECT * FROM ORDERS 
WHERE ONO = ORD_NUM;

CURSOR CUR2
IS
SELECT * FROM ODETAILS
WHERE PNO = PRO_NUM
AND ONO = P_ONO;

VAL1 CUR1%ROWTYPE;
VAL2 CUR2%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

OPEN CUR1;
OPEN CUR2;

LOOP
FETCH CUR1 INTO VAL1;
FETCH CUR2 INTO VAL2;

EXIT WHEN CUR1%NOTFOUND;
EXIT WHEN CUR1%NOTFOUND;


IF VAL1.SHIPPED IS NOT NULL THEN
   IF PRO_NUM = VAL2.PNO AND ORD_NUM = VAL2.ONO THEN
      INSERT INTO (ID_NUMBER, ONO,CNO,DATE_SEND,CONDITION)
      VALUES(Seq.NEXTVAL, VAL1.ONO,VAL1.CNO,SYSDATE,'SEND BACK');
      INSERT INTO REMOVED_ODETAILS(ONO,PNO,QTY) VALUES (VAL2.ONO, VAL2.PNO, VAL2.QTY);
   END IF;  
      DELETE FROM ODETAILS WHERE ONO = ORD_NUM AND PNO = PRO_NUM;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item will be send back ');

-- DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE ONO = ORD_NUM;

ELSIF VAL1.SHIPPED IS NULL THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DO NOTHING ');
END IF;

END LOOP;
CLOSE CUR1;
CLOSE CUR2;
END ONE_BY_ONE;
```

ORDERS

```
    ONO        CNO        ENO      RECEIVED    SHIPPED 
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------   ---------
    1112      1010       9999     18-JAN-16    15-JAN-16
```

ODETAILS

```
     ONO        PNO         QTY
  ---------- ---------- ----------
    1112       12345          1 
    1112       67891          4
```

Answer (score 1):

Just answering your question, you can add to your delete

```
DELETE FROM ORDERS 
WHERE ONO = ORD_NUM and 
NOT EXISTS (select 1 from ODETAILS where ONO = ORD_NUM );
```

After that delete will be executed only if it's the last product in the order.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The code has worked as required! Could this code be done in the counter+? Just curiosity nothing more :)

Comment: Another thought I had that is not mentioned in the question above. If there are more than 1 order in the QTY, how to decrease the QTY -1 if I need to remove an pno from odetail. I will update the ODETAILS table to show you what I mean